# Vertical align bottom divs with text of different sizes

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, font-size, flexbox

Within a flex box, how can I vertical-align the bottom edges of text in two different divs with two different font sizes?

Here is a very simple jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/aegh74dr/1/

You'll notice that the two divs within the flex box contain font of different sizes.  The `align-items` attribute is set to `flex-end`, but the two different divs do not align at the bottom.

Thank you!

Comment: align-items: baseline;

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use:

```
align-items: baseline;
```

Using a value like baseline allows the items to be aligned such as their baselines align.

As Mozilla Developers Networks describes `align-items: baseline;` :

> The baselines (leading edge or trailing edge depending on the
>   flex-direction property) of all flex items are aligned with each
>   other. The flex item that occupies the most space, perpendicular to
>   the layout axis, follows the flex-start rule. The baselines of all
>   remaining elements are then aligned with the baseline of this element.

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/a_incarnati/aegh74dr/2/

Comment: This works!  I completely overlooked the `align-items` attribute.  Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

i managed to get them to line up with this:

```
div.large {
    font-size: 32px;
    height: 32px;
}

div.small {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: .92em;
    height: 16px;
}
```

Comment: I would not recommend this solution.  As soon as you change the `font-size`, you must also change the `line-height`.